# Canon 800d/T7i clean-hdmi?

Tags: live, hdmi, live-recording

I've just bought a Canon 800d to use that as live cam recorder (using elgato game capture).

The problem is that the hdmi output has the focus box and I've managed to remove that only in manual focus mode, but I'd really like to have auto focus.

Do you know any solution?

I think that magic lantern is not yet compatible with the 800d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking foe the same answer for the US version Rebel T7i. Unfortunately only the Pro versions of Canon have the true Mirroring or Clean HDMI out feature BUT by using Cannon Utilities and the USB connection rather than the HDMI mini a clean signal can be accomplished. Canon customer support agreed that this is possible but warned against an over heat issue while using this camera for streaming this way for longer than 20 minutes. They explained the over heat is in the focusing hardware.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I solved using the usb port. I'm using it since august and didn't have any heat issue, for now!

Answer (score 2):

Download Sparkocam and your problem will go away. I am using a T3i and a T6i for the same live steam. Your other option is remove autofocus from the lens and switch it to manual

Answer (score 0):

Canon developed a driver to use with most EOS cameras. Works like charm.
This is available at Canon USA. It is called WebCam Utility.